# Static analysis tools for LLVM IR

Tags: llvm, static-analysis, llvm-ir

I am trying to find if there are any static analysis tools available that perform analysis on LLVM IR and report issues to the developer?

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: LLVM itself, by its very nature, contains a lot of different static analyses. Can you be more specific about what kind of analysis do you want to run?

Comment: A lot of languages have frontend to convert source code to LLVM IR (like C/C++, Fortran, Ruby etc). I am trying to figure out if it is possible to perform static analysis (any kind e.g. symbolic execution, data-flow, control-flow etc) on LLVM IR and report bug to developer providing information in terms of source code(bug description and source code linenumber where it occurred ).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For anyone interested, I have been able to find few research tools that perform analysis on LLVM IR and report errors/warnings to the developer. Following is the list:

1. [KLEE](http://llvm.org/pubs/2008-12-OSDI-KLEE.html) - Runs symbolic execution on LLVM IR generated from C source code and generates a report as explained here: http://klee.github.io/tutorials/testing-regex/.
2. [KLOVER](http://www.cs.utah.edu/%7Eligd/publications/KLOVER-CAV11.pdf) - Built on top of KLEE to generate test cases for C++ programs
3. [LLBMC](http://llbmc.org/) - LLVM IR is converted to Intermediate logical representation, which is converted to SMT-LIB formula. SMT-lib Formula is then solved using SMT solver. More details can be found here: http://llbmc.org/files/papers/ASE13.pdf
4. [LAV](http://argo.matf.bg.ac.rs/?content=lav) - It is a bug finding tool built on top of the LLVM compiler infrastructure. LAV combines symbolic execution, SAT encoding of program's control-flow and some features of bounded model checking.

Comment: Thanks for documenting the findings. Here is a perfect example of a "closed, off topic" question where the answer is indeed very useful.